# If $a,b,c>0\;,$ Then value of $\displaystyle \lfloor \frac{a}{b+c}+\frac{b}{c+a}+\frac{c}{a+b}\rfloor $,

Tags: inequality

> If $a,b,c>0\;,$ Then value of $\displaystyle \bigg \lfloor \frac{a}{b+c}+\frac{b}{c+a}+\frac{c}{a+b}\bigg\rfloor $, Where $\lfloor x \rfloor $ Rep. floor function of $x$.

$\bf{My\; Try::}$ Using $b+c>a$ and $c+a>b$ and $a+b>c$

So $\displaystyle \frac{a}{b+c}+\frac{b}{c+a}+\frac{c}{a+b}<3$

And Using $\bf{A.M\geq H.M}\;,$ we get

$$\frac{a}{b+c}+\frac{b}{c+a}+\frac{c}{a+b}>\frac{9}{\frac{b+c}{a}+\frac{c+a}{b}+\frac{a+b}{c}}$$

I did not Understand How can I calculate its Lower bond, Help Required

Thanks

Comment: It will be $1$ . Is the answer know to you

Comment: Nothing is given about $a,b,c$ except $a,b,c>0$ than how can u say that $“b+c>a ,c+a>b ,a+b>c"$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\frac{a}{b+c}+\frac{b}{c+a}+\frac{c}{a+b}<\frac{a+a}{b+c+a}+\frac{b+b}{c+a+b}+\frac{c+c}{a+b+c}=$$
$$=\frac{2(a+b+c)}{a+b+c}=2$$

And
$$\frac{a}{b+c}+\frac{b}{c+a}+\frac{c}{a+b}>\frac{a}{a+b+c}+\frac{b}{c+a+b}+\frac{c}{a+b+c}=\frac{a+b+c}{a+b+c}=1$$
So
$$ \bigg\lfloor \frac{a}{b+c}+\frac{b}{c+a}+\frac{c}{a+b}\bigg\rfloor =1$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint a small trick is that if you take $3$ numbers greater than $0$ you will always have ywo such pairs whose sum is greater than $3$rd number so division of two pairs will give answer of division as $0<x<1$ thus the sum would always be less than $2$ implying iys sums floor function would be $1$.